# How does WP generate html?

Tags: themes, html

I think this must be a simple question, despite the seemingly broad title. My wordpress theme by default displays several social icons. (You can [see them here](http://www.topblogformula.com/demo/), in the upper right corner.) I'm trying to add a new icon to the existing ones. I've already generated and uploaded a new image, modified all the css and php files that (I think) required modification. However, I'm missing one key thing: somewhere, somehow the theme generates some source html that includes an unordered list that displays the icons:

```
<ul id="socialize-icons">
    <li id="icon-rss"><a href="http://somelink.com">RSS Feed</a></li>
    <li id="icon-facebook"><a href="http://somelink">facebook</a></li>
    <li id="icon-twitter"><a href="http://somelink">twitter</a></li>
</ul>
```

I cannot figure out where this code is generated so that I tweek it to include my new additional icon. If someone could point me in the right direction (a function, some wp documentation), I'd really appreciated it.

Comment: that's probably hardcoded in the theme's footer template

Comment: @Ambitious Amoeba, A-ha! You were right! I can't believe I missed that file. Anyways, if you move your comment to an answer, I'll happily mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ambitious Amoeba indicated above, what I was looking for was hardcoded in the footer template.

Answer (score 4):

HTML markup can be generated in several ways:

- directly included in theme's [template files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates);
- generated by [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) in templates;
- generated by native or plugin functions attached to [hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters).

From quick look at this specific theme's code I found this:

```
array(  "name" => "Socialize Icons",
            "desc" => "Enter Links to Your Twitter, Facebook, and RSS feeds.<br />If you want to remove the icon, clear the field and save this page",
            "type" => "socialize_icons"),
```

Which makes me think it has theme options page, where you can change or make blank those fields.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had already tweeked the code you referenced above, but it wasn't enough. :\ I knew there had to be one last template I was missing, as @Ambitious Amoeba pointed out.